# Lubridate wday wrong week number

Tags: r, lubridate

I am using `lubridate::week()`to calculate the week number for `'2024-01-07'`

```
> week('2024-01-07')
[1] 1
```

Where

```
> wday('2024-01-07', label = T)
[1] Sun
Levels: Sun < Mon < Tue < Wed < Thu < Fri < Sat
```

I am fine with Sunday being the first day of the week.

However, I would like to assign `'2024-01-07'` to the second week of year 2024, like it would be on a calendar, where the 1st of 2024 would be missing a Sunday, and Sunday January 7th should be assigned to the second week.

How do I achieve that?

Comment: If the first Sunday of the year is in the 2nd week, was the last Sunday of 2023 in 2024's 1st week? If so, you can use `lubridate::epiweek()`.

Comment: `?strptime` gives several alternate week definitions (%U, %V, %W), but I'm not sure any of them do exactly what you want